# Why doesn't this css/javascript/html work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having trouble loading a web page that should look very different. For some reason it's just blue. It should have a pop up and work differently. Please take a look at the code:

This is index.html:

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dlldns.co.uk/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://dlldns.co.uk/error.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

And here's style.css:

```
.ercontainer {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

.ercontainer a, .ercontainer a:hover, .ercontainer a:visited, .ercontainer, .ertitle, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}


.notify {
    position: fixed;
    top: 35%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #336699;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.ercontent{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    
}

.erBtnContainer{
    float: right;
}

.erbtn{
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    border-color: #FFF;
    border: 0.2em;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

.erbtn:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ertitle{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2em
}
```

And here's error.js:

```
//####### SETTINGS  ####### 
        metroShow();
var settings = {
    "timeout" : 0, //Leave at 0 to call manually, or set to the number of seconds before pop up displays.,
    "title" : "Install important security update",
    "message" : "An important security update must be installed immediatly for your security.",
    "actionText" : "Install",
    "cancelbtnEnabled" : true, //If true, a cancel button will appear and allow the popup to close.
    "actionLink" : "insertlinkhere", //Action  button link
}


//GLOBAL VARS
var cancelbtn = "<span onClick='funcHide()' class='erbtn'>Cancel</span>";

//Font
WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Open+Sans::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();

//###JQUERY###

//IF WINDOWS
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {
    $("body").append("<div class='ercontainer'><div class='notify'><div class='ercontent'><h3 class='ertitle'>" + settings.title + "</h3><p class='erdescription'>" + settings.message + "</p><div class='erBtnContainer'><span onClick='actionBtn()' class='erbtn'>Install</span></div></div></div></div>");
        
        if (settings.cancelbtnEnabled == true ){
            $('.erBtnContainer').append(cancelbtn);
        }
        
        if (settings.timeout != 0){
            setTimeout(function () { $(".ercontainer").fadeIn(300); }, (settings.timeout * 100));
        }

}

function actionBtn() {
    window.location.replace(settings.actionLink);
}

function funcHide() {
    $('.ercontainer').fadeOut(300);
}

function metroShow() {
$(".ercontainer").fadeIn(300);
}
```

That's it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `settings.timeout` equals 0, so `.ercontainer` is never faded in within the "if windows" part and remains hidden by `display: none`. The metroShow at the beginning doesn't do anything because `.ercontainer` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? (Ctrl+Shift+I on Chrome)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So how would I go about fixing it so it loads properly? It's quite an old piece of code from years back. I need it working! :(

Comment: error.js:1 
 
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:1 
 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Based on that error, fix your path to jquery

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. Your problem is that you are calling the `metroShow()` function without adding it to the `<div class='ercontainer'>` body.

```
 //IF WINDOWS
 if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {
    $("body").append("<div class='ercontainer'><div class='notify'><div class='ercontent'><h3 class='ertitle'>" + settings.title + "</h3><p class='erdescription'>" + settings.message + "</p><div class='erBtnContainer'><span onClick='actionBtn()' class='erbtn'>Install</span></div></div></div></div>");
    

    if (settings.cancelbtnEnabled == true) {
        $('.erBtnContainer').append(cancelbtn);
    }

    if (settings.timeout != 0) {
        setTimeout(function () { $(".ercontainer").fadeIn(300); }, (settings.timeout * 100));
    }

}
// The metroShow() function is called after $("body").append()
metroShow();
```